# Execute XSLT on an XML-Schema rather than an XML document

Tags: xslt, xsd

I know that the input of an XSLT processor is a source XML document that will be transformed into a target XML document.

In my case, I haven't  a source XML document but I have a source XML-SCHEMA and I want to know through the XSLT document information about the mappings between the  source  XML-SCHEMA and the target one.

Thus, I have the idea of **executing or maybe parsing** the XSLT **on the source  XML-SCHEMA** in order to get this information.

I'm really confused about the difference between execute and parse an XSLT document.
I think that to execute an XSLT document, an XSLT processor firstly parses it to transform it to another internal representation.
What is this  internal representation??

I really need your help

Comment: It is entirely up to the implementation of the XSLT processor how it internally represents the XSLT code to execute it. For instance Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` in the .NET framework parses the XSLT code and compiles it into the MSIL code to be then executed by the .NET runtime. In the Java world you can find XSLT processors that compile to Java byte code to be executed by the JRE.

Comment: An XML Schema file **is an XML file**, so it's a perfectly valid input for an XSLT transformation. Having said that, it's difficult to help you since your question does not clearly states what is your *input* (one schema? two schemas? schemas and stylesheet?) and what is the *output* you expect.

Comment: Related question (same author and similar subject, made some time ago, remained unanswered probably because of some vagueness): http://stackoverflow.com/q/27398219/4453460

Comment: @ lfurini my input is a source xml-schema and a stylesheet that describes transformation rules of instances of this source xml-schema to instances of another target xml-schema.

Comment: Ok for the input, and what is the expected output? Could you add a (short) example of input and output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm really confused about the difference between execute and parse an
>   XSLT document.

To ***parse*** a language, including XML, is to analyse it into parts.

To ***execute*** a language, including XSLT, is to perform the instructions specified by the language.

It does not make sense to talk about executing XML because XML itself specifies no instruction.

It does make sense to talk about ***validating*** XML against the grammar given by its XSD.

> I think that to execute an XSLT document, an XSLT processor firstly
>   parses it to transform it to another internal representation. What is
>   this internal representation??

You do *not* need to know an XSLT processor's internal representation because that is an implementation detail.

**You *do* need to know that an XSLT processor parses an input XML document, executes an XSLT transformation, and generates output.**  (It also parses the XML that represents the XSLT, but that's beside the point.)

The input XML document typically is not an XSD.  You might want to consider the XSD associated with the input XML document in order to anticipate allowed input variations.  In *rare* circumstances you might want to transform the XSD itself in some way, and you can do so since an XSD is represented in XML.  In other *rare* circumstances, you might want to transform XSLT itself in some way, and you can do so since XSLT is also represented in XML.  But, **normally, the input to an XSLT transformation is a mundane XML document instance, not an XSD, and not other XSLT.**